# boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name() is not "pretty"

Tags: c++, boost, rtti, typeinfo

I am trying to have the type of some variable printed on stdout. This code:

```
std::string mystr {"dsadsadas"};
std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id< decltype(mystr) >().pretty_name() << std::endl;
```

results in:

```
std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1:: allocator<char> >
```

which is definitely not pretty.. why is this happening? any workaround?? (Note I'm compiling with clang++ using c++14 semantics)

Comment: I doubt the output you show come from the code you show, as the code is a plain simple `std::string` and not a `std::multimap`. Other than that it *is* the "pretty" name, as otherwise you would get the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) which is *not* pretty.

Comment: sorry, I pasted the wrong snippet - I've just updated the answer with the right output. So isn't there any way to arrive at just std::sting, somehow ?

Comment: @MarinosK What do you mean _not "pretty"?_ That's actually the type definition `std::string` results in, do you rather want to see the mangled name?

Comment: What are you hoping for, `std::string`?  That is an alias, under the standard.

Comment: ok got it - std::string is the pretty name.. thank you.

Comment: @MarinosK `typedef`'d or alias (`using`) types, don't form a new type, thus you see what `std::string` was aliased from.

Comment: If I understand correctly Boost.TypeIndex has a mechanism for declaring custom names for specific types. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex/making_a_custom_type_index.html . However I was never able to make it work. Did you solve the problem using Boost.TypeIndex ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a library called cpputil (privately maintained on bitbucket) which has lots of useful shortcuts for c++11 or better.

one of the concepts is `cpputil::classname_of(x)`.

The idea is that if a class has a static member data or function called `classname`, this is used to print the name of the class. If not, you can supply a free function that provides the classname. Failing that, `typeid.name()` is used as a fallback.

Now your classnames can be as pretty as you like.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cfc528ee2fc497c)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

/// static member of any type
namespace cpputil {
namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_static_member_classname(...)
    -> std::false_type
    {
        return {};
    }

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_static_member_classname(int)
    -> decltype(T::classname, void(), std::true_type())
    {
        return {};
    }

    // static member of type function that returns anything but takes no args

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_static_function_classname(...)
    -> std::false_type
    { return {}; }

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_static_function_classname(int)
    -> decltype(T::classname(), void(), std::true_type())
    { return {}; }
}
// templated free function that takes no args, used as a fallback but may be overriden

template<class T> decltype(auto) classname() { return typeid(T).name(); }

namespace detail {
    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_free_function_classname_0(...)
    -> std::false_type
    { return {}; }

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_free_function_classname_0(int)
    -> decltype(classname<T>(), void(), std::true_type())
    { return {}; }

    // free function that takes a const ref

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_free_function_classname_1(...)
    -> std::false_type
    { return {}; }

    template<class T>
    constexpr auto has_free_function_classname_1(int)
    -> decltype(classname(std::declval<T>()), void(), std::true_type())
    { return {}; }


    template<class T, typename = void>
    struct classname_finder;

        // highest priority - if there is a free function taking 1 parameter findable by ADL - use this
        template<class T>
        struct classname_finder<
        T,
        std::enable_if_t<
        decltype(has_free_function_classname_1<T>(0))::value
        >
        >
        {
            static constexpr decltype(auto) apply() { return classname(*reinterpret_cast<const T*>(0)); }
            static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(const T& t) { return classname(t); }
        };


        // priority 2 - if there is a static function, use that
        template<class T>
        struct classname_finder<
        T,
        std::enable_if_t<
        decltype(has_static_function_classname<T>(0))::value &&
        !decltype(has_free_function_classname_1<T>(0))::value
        >
        >
        {
            static constexpr decltype(auto) apply() { return T::classname(); }
            static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(const T&) { return T::classname(); }
        };

        // priority 3 - if there is a static data member, use that
    template<class T>
    struct classname_finder<
        T,
        std::enable_if_t<
            decltype(has_static_member_classname<T>(0))::value &&
            !decltype(has_static_function_classname<T>(0))::value &&
            !decltype(has_free_function_classname_1<T>(0))::value
        >
    >
    {
        static constexpr decltype(auto) apply() { return T::classname; }
        static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(const T&) { return T::classname; }
    };

        // finally, use the cpputil::classname_of<X>() template overload
    template<class T>
    struct classname_finder<
        T,
        std::enable_if_t<
            !decltype(has_static_member_classname<T>(0))::value &&
            !decltype(has_static_function_classname<T>(0))::value &&
            !decltype(has_free_function_classname_1<T>(0))::value &&
            decltype(has_free_function_classname_0<T>(0))::value
        >
    >
    {
        static constexpr decltype(auto) apply() { return classname<T>(); }
        static constexpr decltype(auto) apply(const T&) { return classname<T>(); }
    };
}


template<class T>
auto classname_of(const T& t)
{
    return detail::classname_finder<T>::apply(t);
}

template<class T>
auto classname_of()
{
    return detail::classname_finder<T>::apply();
}
}

struct class_a
{
    static const char* classname() { return "class_a"; }
};

struct class_b
{
    constexpr static const char* classname = "class_b";
};

struct class_c
{
};
namespace cpputil {
    template<> decltype(auto) classname<class_c>() { return "class_c"; }
}

struct class_d
{
};

decltype(auto) classname(const class_d&) { return "class_d"; }

struct class_e {
    static const std::string& classname() { static const std::string _("class_e static function"); return _; }
};
static const char* classname(const class_e&) {
    return "class_e free function should take priority";
}

// no classname decoration. should fall back to typeid() solution
struct class_f {

};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    class_a a;
    class_b b;
    class_c c;
    class_d d;
    class_e e;
    class_f f;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(a) << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(b) << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(c) << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(d) << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(e) << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of(f) << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_a>() << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_b>() << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_c>() << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_d>() << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_e>() << endl;
    cout << cpputil::classname_of<class_f>() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Prints

```
class_a
class_b
class_c
class_d
class_e free function should take priority
7class_f

class_a
class_b
class_c
class_d
class_e free function should take priority
7class_f
```

Comment: It doesn't work for templates like boost pretty_name.

Comment: Yes, since I wrote this I discovered that boost had a facility for this which uses the cxxabi library. The only problem with the boost solution is that it uses runtime code to build the pretty name whereas the one above gets constant-folded. YMMV.